# Angular Stepper - Issue with addControl and validators

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-forms

I'm currently developing a stepper in Angular. I'm facing a challenge when I use **addControl** on a **formControl** that I've imported within a child component. When the control I add has validators, the **formControl** does not immediately switch to **valid : false**. I need to go to the next or previous step for the value to get updated.

To provide a clearer picture of the issue I'm encountering, I've created a StackBlitz demo: [Link to StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qempvb?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fstepper1%2Fstepper1.component.ts,src%2Fstepper2%2Fstepper2.component.ts,src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fstepper3%2Fstepper3.component.ts)

The main areas of concern in the code are:

- src/main.ts
- src/stepper1/stepper1.component.ts
- src/stepper2/stepper2.component.ts
- src/app.component.ts
- src/app.module.ts
- src/stepper3/stepper3.component.ts

Any assistance or insights on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes, that changes, but...

when you load a child component and change something this not working like two way binding, if you do something like this:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.formGroup) {
        this.formGroup.addControl(
          '_name',
          this.fb.control('', [Validators.required])
        );
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
```

this is because all html in the child component is loaded before adding a new control

how avoid that, u can suscribe to form on parent control

```
this.formStep2.valueChanges.subscribe((e) => {
      console.log(this.formStep2);
    });
```